# hyperledger-fabric bin folder missing

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to install Hyperledger Fabric v1.1.0 I am following http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html but when I run curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0 it does not create bin folder that should contain cryptogen.

Running first-network sample under fabric-samples using ./byfn.sh -m generate gives error "cryptogen tool not found. exiting"

console output
$ git clone -b master https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git
Cloning into 'fabric-samples'...
remote: Counting objects: 1464, done.
remote: Total 1464 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1463
Receiving objects: 100% (1464/1464), 533.28 KiB | 317.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (683/683), done.
Checking out files: 100% (340/340), done.

abbasf@LAP-TIG132 ~
$ cd fabric-samples

abbasf@LAP-TIG132 ~/fabric-samples
$ git tag v1.1.0
fatal: tag 'v1.1.0' already exists

abbasf@LAP-TIG132 ~/fabric-samples
$ git checkout v1.1.0
Note: checking out 'v1.1.0'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

git checkout -b

HEAD is now at 1252c7a [FAB-8920] Pin fabric-samples to node.js "~1.1.0"

abbasf@LAP-TIG132 ~/fabric-samples
$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0

Installing hyperledger/fabric-samples repo

===> Checking out v1.1.0 branch of hyperledger/fabric-samples
HEAD is now at 1252c7a [FAB-8920] Pin fabric-samples to node.js "~1.1.0"

Installing Hyperledger Fabric binaries

===> Downloading version x86_64-1.1.0 platform specific fabric binaries
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1169    0  1169    0     0    763      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--   765

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
==> There was an error downloading the binary file. Switching to incremental download.
==> Downloading file...

------> x86_64-1.1.0 platform specific fabric binary is not available to download <----

===> Downloading version x86_64-1.1.0 platform specific fabric-ca-client binary
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1196    0  1196    0     0   1214      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1226

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
==> There was an error downloading the binary file. Switching to incremental download.
==> Downloading file...

------> x86_64-1.1.0 fabric-ca-client binary is not available to download  (Available from 1.1.0-rc1) <----

Installing Hyperledger Fabric docker images

===> Pulling fabric Images
==> FABRIC IMAGE: peer

x86_64-1.1.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-peer
1be7f2b886e8: Pull complete
6fbc4a21b806: Pull complete
c71a6f8e1378: Pull complete
4be3072e5a37: Pull complete
06c6d2f59700: Pull complete
4d536120d8a5: Pull complete
0baaf9ec263e: Pull complete
770563795186: Pull complete
15763b7bd14b: Pull complete
62f2823da7f3: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:57417699ddf50c5ebd47a9a2cc74c0324fbba0281eb1104b9ddd05a67776b01f
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0
==> FABRIC IMAGE: orderer

x86_64-1.1.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-orderer
1be7f2b886e8: Already exists
6fbc4a21b806: Already exists
c71a6f8e1378: Already exists
4be3072e5a37: Already exists
06c6d2f59700: Already exists
4d536120d8a5: Already exists
0baaf9ec263e: Already exists
770563795186: Already exists
61d33418a569: Pull complete
b1b98004e7c6: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:0c3a3b5ecfd24b513da22bbb77da7b3f5bca9c121cc0ac5c46ba04c97c163654
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0
==> FABRIC IMAGE: ccenv

x86_64-1.1.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-ccenv
1be7f2b886e8: Already exists
6fbc4a21b806: Already exists
c71a6f8e1378: Already exists
4be3072e5a37: Already exists
06c6d2f59700: Already exists
4d536120d8a5: Already exists
0baaf9ec263e: Already exists
3ea9b6cc6f21: Pull complete
6173b9a5fe5e: Pull complete
e73719e0bcbe: Pull complete
b55408c6ced5: Pull complete
e1267c65ed62: Pull complete
2839c20999d1: Pull complete
444429f2833f: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:07818367dc6d4264472d24b21819f9dc4e16e890d81ddfacee0341a22d72050b
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:x86_64-1.1.0
==> FABRIC IMAGE: javaenv

x86_64-1.1.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-javaenv
1be7f2b886e8: Already exists
6fbc4a21b806: Already exists
c71a6f8e1378: Already exists
4be3072e5a37: Already exists
06c6d2f59700: Already exists
4d536120d8a5: Already exists
0baaf9ec263e: Already exists
3ea9b6cc6f21: Already exists
6173b9a5fe5e: Already exists
e73719e0bcbe: Already exists
b55408c6ced5: Already exists
d72e92165d22: Pull complete
bbb7025c0883: Pull complete
8fa39f27c772: Pull complete
5187f67cb3f8: Pull complete
05488c815030: Pull complete
3bd91626e779: Pull complete
47aa3719a5d6: Pull complete
cd3dc7bf95ff: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:d2588c0556b6fc79131f638b02a7a77337363e2c2f38a9c47798a6d99bd2f20e
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-javaenv:x86_64-1.1.0
==> FABRIC IMAGE: tools

x86_64-1.1.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-tools
1be7f2b886e8: Already exists
6fbc4a21b806: Already exists
c71a6f8e1378: Already exists
4be3072e5a37: Already exists
06c6d2f59700: Already exists
4d536120d8a5: Already exists
0baaf9ec263e: Already exists
3ea9b6cc6f21: Already exists
6173b9a5fe5e: Already exists
e73719e0bcbe: Already exists
b55408c6ced5: Already exists
1a8bca84adfa: Pull complete
b54c1992cc9c: Pull complete
68093aff3e84: Pull complete
3827dc0ff46d: Pull complete
1e22360bf4e7: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:36d7fa8e8ddcc19fed8e1c3c06bc6ae1dac18c35e8a884188d2c08df3e5a4472
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.1.0
===> Pulling fabric ca Image
==> FABRIC CA IMAGE

x86_64-1.1.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-ca
1be7f2b886e8: Already exists
6fbc4a21b806: Already exists
c71a6f8e1378: Already exists
4be3072e5a37: Already exists
06c6d2f59700: Already exists
4d536120d8a5: Already exists
0baaf9ec263e: Already exists
ab27f0b1192c: Pull complete
7e1142a727eb: Pull complete
a7624c188c44: Pull complete
0c8524afd242: Pull complete
23e14758f709: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:92f44d0811cddb0d335f7879f7e3b3c4b631f31740c76f3e7b85438c244b03f4
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0
===> Pulling thirdparty docker images
==> THIRDPARTY DOCKER IMAGE: couchdb

x86_64-0.4.6: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
8f7c85c2269a: Pull complete
9e72e494a6dd: Pull complete
3009ec50c887: Pull complete
9d5ffccbec91: Pull complete
e872a2642ce1: Pull complete
9b84958a26b3: Pull complete
68d4ced7ec19: Pull complete
ff1d2b44d88d: Pull complete
99e6a41c35bd: Pull complete
87b2e4a0b9d2: Pull complete
55f108d3ee4a: Pull complete
9e76f6c2c001: Pull complete
368be4b23f81: Pull complete
581042703e1f: Pull complete
18c50435ee69: Pull complete
70dbffc27ecb: Pull complete
31c35dd1bd00: Pull complete
7571e6af230f: Pull complete
9ef1e88f8344: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:4278269b115cfd0f24251b5381407be9ccdf396c1470c69e1ee2ff16917ac882
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.6
==> THIRDPARTY DOCKER IMAGE: kafka

x86_64-0.4.6: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-kafka
8f7c85c2269a: Already exists
9e72e494a6dd: Already exists
3009ec50c887: Already exists
9d5ffccbec91: Already exists
e872a2642ce1: Already exists
9b84958a26b3: Already exists
68d4ced7ec19: Already exists
ff1d2b44d88d: Already exists
99e6a41c35bd: Already exists
87b2e4a0b9d2: Already exists
55f108d3ee4a: Already exists
76d29739374b: Pull complete
8e29d2dddc78: Pull complete
6bb3eb1b6cb1: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:738bb79f02aa505a9ab0553a865122605ffba91d1b5de6eb0429f7287e83ac7c
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-kafka:x86_64-0.4.6
==> THIRDPARTY DOCKER IMAGE: zookeeper

x86_64-0.4.6: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper
8f7c85c2269a: Already exists
9e72e494a6dd: Already exists
3009ec50c887: Already exists
9d5ffccbec91: Already exists
e872a2642ce1: Already exists
9b84958a26b3: Already exists
68d4ced7ec19: Already exists
ff1d2b44d88d: Already exists
99e6a41c35bd: Already exists
87b2e4a0b9d2: Already exists
55f108d3ee4a: Already exists
f876628e022b: Pull complete
5e8448f14014: Pull complete
c1ddd9fcc9fe: Pull complete
cae637096fa7: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:7fda667f6c39d6cb87125c132962fc3e434a8e6b2b16ee798d6fa94f970531a2
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper:x86_64-0.4.6

===> List out hyperledger docker images
hyperledger/fabric-ca          latest              72617b4fa9b4        6 weeks ago         299MB
hyperledger/fabric-ca          x86_64-1.1.0        72617b4fa9b4        6 weeks ago         299MB
hyperledger/fabric-tools       latest              b7bfddf508bc        6 weeks ago         1.46GB
hyperledger/fabric-tools       x86_64-1.1.0        b7bfddf508bc        6 weeks ago         1.46GB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer     latest              ce0c810df36a        6 weeks ago         180MB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer     x86_64-1.1.0        ce0c810df36a        6 weeks ago         180MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer        latest              b023f9be0771        6 weeks ago         187MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer        x86_64-1.1.0        b023f9be0771        6 weeks ago         187MB
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv     latest              82098abb1a17        6 weeks ago         1.52GB
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv     x86_64-1.1.0        82098abb1a17        6 weeks ago         1.52GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv       latest              c8b4909d8d46        6 weeks ago         1.39GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv       x86_64-1.1.0        c8b4909d8d46        6 weeks ago         1.39GB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper   latest              92cbb952b6f8        2 months ago        1.39GB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper   x86_64-0.4.6        92cbb952b6f8        2 months ago        1.39GB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka       latest              554c591b86a8        2 months ago        1.4GB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka       x86_64-0.4.6        554c591b86a8        2 months ago        1.4GB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb     latest              7e73c828fc5b        2 months ago        1.56GB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb     x86_64-0.4.6        7e73c828fc5b        2 months ago        1.56GB

Comment: can you please share a gist or pastebin of the output of running the curl command?

Comment: Console output added.

Comment: for future reference, please use gist or pastebin to post lengthy terminal or logfile output. I just ran the script and it worked fine. Not sure why but seems like possibly your tarfile was corrupted. Please try again.

Comment: Having the same issue. Bin folder with the tools is never created. Any updates?

Answer (score 2):

Just execute this command in terminal from where ever you want your bin folder to be.

[image: command to execute in terminal]

This will download all the required images and cryptogen tools as well. Make sure to add the bin path to your $PATH for example :

```
export PATH=$PATH:opt/ibm/node/bin:/usr/local/docker:/usr/local/go/bin:<path_to_your_download_location>/bin
```

Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

I tried it using git bash and it worked and created complete folder structure including bin folder. Somehow it was not creating bin folder when I was doing it through command prompt or cygwin.